# ASP.Net Core 2.2 - Azure SAS Tokens?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to figure out how to generate a time based token for users to access data that is stored in an Azure Storage Account Blob container.  Users upload various data (PDFs, images) but I don't want links to this data to be public.  The recommended strategy was to use a SAS token which I was able to get this working under .Net using the following function which I found on the MS site about a year ago:

```
        //Function for getting a temporary Azure SAS 
        public static string GetAzureSASToken(string userhashid, int minutes)
        {

            //Get Azure SAS Token so we can allow them to temporarily view the photos 
            UploadedFileInfo uploadedfileinfo = new UploadedFileInfo();

            //Azure User containter must be all lowercase!!
            uploadedfileinfo.usercontainer = "user-" + userhashid;
            uploadedfileinfo.azureurl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureURL"].ToString() + uploadedfileinfo.usercontainer + "/";


            // Retrieve storage account from connection string.
            string azureconnection = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString");

            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(azureconnection);

            CloudBlobClient client = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = client.GetContainerReference(uploadedfileinfo.usercontainer);

            //Set the expiry time and permissions for the container.
            //In this case no start time is specified, so the shared access signature becomes valid immediately.
            SharedAccessBlobPolicy sasConstraints = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy();
            sasConstraints.SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(minutes);
            sasConstraints.Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read;

            //Generate the shared access signature on the container, setting the constraints directly on the signature.
            string sasContainerToken = blobContainer.GetSharedAccessSignature(sasConstraints);

            return sasContainerToken;

        }
```

The problem is that I now need to access these files from an **Asp.Net Core 2.2** app and I can't seem to figure out how to replicate the code to get the token (the Core libraries are different)

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this in .Net Core 2.2?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just install the latest nuget package [Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob -Version 11.1.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob/).

Then your .net core code( same as .net framework code in your post) can work well as .net framework code.

Here is an sample code of .net core 2.2. I didn't read the settings from configure file, so it's a little different:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage;
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Auth;
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string sas = GetAzureSASToken();

            Console.WriteLine(sas);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static string GetAzureSASToken()
        {

            string accountName = "xxx";
            string accountKey = "xxx";

            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey), true);

            CloudBlobClient client = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = client.GetContainerReference("test1");

            //Set the expiry time and permissions for the container.
            //In this case no start time is specified, so the shared access signature becomes valid immediately.
            SharedAccessBlobPolicy sasConstraints = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy();
            sasConstraints.SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5);
            sasConstraints.Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read;

            //Generate the shared access signature on the container, setting the constraints directly on the signature.
            string sasContainerToken = blobContainer.GetSharedAccessSignature(sasConstraints);

            return sasContainerToken;
        }
    }
}
```

And the test result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  I was using Azure.Storage.Blobs, not Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blobs.  :-|